# How do i make the user able to go to another screen in a windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I was making a windows form application with Visual Studio 2008 and i was wondering if i could make the user go to another screen instead of being on the same screen. I was coding with Visual C#. Thank you

Comment: You should probably read some tutorials before posting questions like this.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes.

Comment: But how is what im asking

Comment: We expect you to have put in at least a little bit of effort before coming here to ask a question. What have you tried? What sources have you read up on?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've added another Form to your project called "frmRegister", you could open it with code like this in a button click event handler:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmRegister register = new frmRegister();
        register.Show();
    }
```